# finding the extension a file on upload?

Tags: php, file, directory

what im trying to do here, get the current file and then upload it,find the extension of the file and rename it! and echo the result!! but it seems wrong, and i dnt know which part!! :((

```
    $fieldname = $_REQUEST['fieldname'];
    $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES[$fieldname]['name']);


    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

    //find the extension
     $extension= pathinfo($uploadfile);

    //rename the file
      rename ($uploadfile, "newfile.".$extenion['extension']."");
 echo "uploads/newfile.'".$extension['extension']."'"; // "success"

}
```

Comment: EXtra: im only renaming the file after the upload is becuase i, when i rename on the move_uploaded_file, it deosnt reconise the extension!!

Comment: came here to look for a solution, but saw a typo in your script: `$extenion['extension']` instead of `$extension['extension']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do something like this:

```
$fieldname = $_POST['fieldname']; // don't use $_REQUEST
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES[$fieldname]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . 'newfile.'.$extension;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    // success
}
```

`move_uploaded_file` already "renames" the file, there is no need to call `rename` manually. Just make it in a single operation.

You probably also noticed that I've passed `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` to `pathinfo`, since you need only the extension and not the complete path information.

Lastly, I used `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`. You shouldn't use `$_REQUEST` unless you really know what you are doing. This could lead to unexpected variables tampering from cookies or session, per example.

Comment: thanks, this works, but how do i rename the file with the extension! could you show me an example, sorry for being a pain in the ass!

Comment: @Jhon: It already supposed to be there. `pathinfo` is kind of useless here, I just assumed you may need the extension later. `basename` does not strip the extension from the file. What output are you getting then?

Comment: @netcoder, im getting photo.jpg which is the actual name of the upload, but i want to rename it to newfile.jpg,

Comment: net coder, theres a problem, when the file is uploaded its named `newfile.tmp` isnt it meant to be newfile.jpg

Comment: @Jhon: Are you sure you are using `name` and not `tmp_name` within `pathinfo`? The only reason this could happen is either that, or the original filename is called `photo.tmp`.

Comment: @netcoder your a genius oh my god i have been trying for like 2 days, and u solved in like 3 minutes, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new filename as the second argument to `move_uploaded_file`:

```
$fieldname = $_REQUEST['fieldname'];
$tmpfile = $_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'];

$info = pathinfo($tmpfile);
$filename = 'newfile.' . $info['extension'];

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $filename;

if(move_uploaded_file($tmpfile, $uploadfile)) {
    echo $uploadfile;
}
```

Comment: thank very much this works when you change $tmpfile=$_FILES['fieldname']['tmp_name'], from request to files, but then the file thats gets uploaded is called newfile.tmp instead of newfile.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
$fieldname = $_POST['fieldname']; #its never going to be a GET! ..not sure y u need this though, the file field should hold the array key, but anyway...
#get the extension by removing everything before the last dot
$extension = preg_replace('@.+\.@', '', $_FILES[$fieldname]['name']);
$newname = "newfile.".$extension;

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $newname;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

 echo "$uploadfile"; // "success"

}
```

Untested, but the logic is mo straight to the point.

Comment: but i love the way you got the extension!!

Comment: :) Well, it WAS untested, but glad you like all the same.