# Display img from database with php not working

Tags: php, html, css, web

I managed to upload images into a database(lonblob). I have issues display that image:

Upload:

```
if(isset($_POST['pic_upload'])){
    if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == FALSE){
        echo "Please select an image.";
    }else{
        $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image= file_get_contents($image);
        $image= base64_encode($image);
        saveimage($name,$image);
    }
}
```

saveimage(writes the $image into a db field(type longblob))

Get images:

```
function get_image($userid){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE user_id = ".$userid."";
    $result = execute_sql($sql);
    return $result;
}
```

display image:

```
<?php 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($img);
    echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row[3]).'">'; 
?>
```

The upload works perfectly, but the image doesn't appear on the site.

Comment: You already base64_encode before saving so why do you have to base64_encode again before displaying?

Comment: You should consider using prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: An SQL injection is only able to do its dirty work when the SQL string has direct contact with POST, Get or Cookie data. A user ID is usually a select from the database and stored in a server sided var. No thread detected here.

Comment: What are you using `addslashes` on `$image` and `$name` for? As a security measure for either a file system or a database query context, it would be completely the wrong tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're encoding it twice.

```
<?php 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($img);
    echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$row[3].'">'; 
?>
```

Also, I would recommend looking at `pathinfo()`, [finding the extension a file on upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595633/finding-the-extension-a-file-on-upload)